# How can I access from one ViewScoped bean to another?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jsf-2

I plan to use one `*.xhtml` page with a few JSF Managed Beans in Tomcat. All beans I want to be `ViewScoped`. I need to pass some data (usualy one simple POJO) from one bean to another, but...

`@managedProperty` doesn't work.

`findBean("someBean")` - unknown identifier.

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sessionBean");` -   works with `SessionScoped` beans. What's about `ViewScoped`?

I don't want to pass integer identifier via `GET` parameters for security reasons.
Theoricaly, I can use `SessionScoped` bean for transferring data, but is it best solution?

Is any ways to access from one ViewScoped bean to another like `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()...`?

I guess, that all `ViewScoped` beans instantiated at one time and ther lifecycles the same. Am I right?

Thanks for wasting your time for me.

Comment: `@ManagedProperty` should work. What are you trying to access in your bean?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty("#{otherBean}")
    private OtherBean otherBean;
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class OtherBean implements Serializable {
}
```

Getting the beans from the viewMap may work but it's dead ugly and you can't/shouldn't do this to class fields.

Comment: Souch example doesn't work. I wrote getters, setters for `OtherBean`, but no result. `OtherBean` is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().get("beanName")` works fine.